# UDK "Error, 'DefaultMesh': Bad command or expression"

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm porting UT3 code to UDK, and I am getting the following compile error with the UDK compiler:

> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-03\Development\Src\FixIt\Classes\ZPawn.uc(25) : Error, 'DefaultMesh': Bad command or expression

The ZPawn class extends UTPawn.

Line 25 is the following:

```
DefaultMesh = SkeletalMesh(DynamicLoadObject(ZBotOwner(Owner).MeshToUse, class'SkeletalMesh'));
```

Where did DefaultMesh go in UDK?

Comment: I think the answer lies in this page, though I'm currently on spring break so I don't have time to sit down and figure it out at the moment. If anyone else wants to, that'd be great: http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=707342&page=2

Comment: Here is another resource: http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=720942&highlight=DefaultMesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SkeletalMesh is part of the Mesh Component in a Pawn:

```
Begin Object Class=SkeletalMeshComponent  name=Mesh01
    SkeletalMesh=SkeletalMesh'pawnPackage.Meshes.mySkeletalMesh'
    AnimTreeTemplate=AnimTree'pawnPackage.Anims.myAnimTree'
    PhysicsAsset=PhysicsAsset'pawnPackage.Physics.myPhysicsAsset'
    AnimSets(0) =AnimSet'pawnPackage.Anims.myAnimSet'             
End Object
Mesh=Mesh01
Components.Add(Mesh01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just to be clear, the line change you will want will be this:

```
Mesh = SkeletalMesh(DynamicLoadObject(ZBotOwner(Owner).MeshToUse, class'SkeletalMesh'));
```

Assuming of course your ZBot is all set up correctly.
Also I'm assumign that this is in default properties? Don't forget to add it to your components

```
Components.Add(Mesh);
```